#  A simple Custom Behavior does not work even though I've followed steps perfectly

Tags: wcf

I am hosting a Website at localhost and the WCF service at localhost/Service, both on IIS 7.5. There's a tiny AJAX code in Default.aspx that calls that WCF service. But, I needed to intercept from client side before it actually reaches the WCF service. I've written a Message Inspector. But it never seems to hit breakpoint at ApplyClientBehavior. I've perfectly followed the steps and researched a lot, and I find no problem with my implementation.

You can download the code from: http://codingproblems.codeplex.com/releases/view/62808#DownloadId=218825

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: "Your code is not yet published" at the link you posted.

Comment: Sorry about that. You can download the code from here: http://codingproblems.codeplex.com/releases/view/62808#DownloadId=218825

Comment: Can anyone please help me to solve this very simple problem?